# insert an element before the number in an ol in html

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Is it possible to create an ordered list (could be nested), in which there are html elements to the left of each number? Here is a rough example:

[image]

I've played around with the :before in css but I realized that you can't insert html content there. Is it possible to do this organically or would I have to resort to some "hack" in order to achieve this.

Comment: It might help if you show us what you tried and what didn't work about it.

Comment: I tried using relative positioning, and giving a negative "left" attribute but it messes with spacing and isn't consistent with a single digit number vs a multi digit number. Example here: http://i.imgur.com/I2hBykO.png, and here: http://i.imgur.com/aSqjQAo.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it with positioning, but you need to use `absolute` instead of `relative`.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmky4/14/)

Comment: THANK you this is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmky4/11/) allows you to insert an image to the left using `background` in CSS:

**HTML:**

```
<ol class="img">
<li>(group) As only</li>
<ol class="img">
  <li>AB</li>
  <li>AC</li>
</ol>
<li>(group) Bs only</li>
  <ol class="img">
    <li>BA</li>
    <li>BC</li>
  </ol>
<li>(group) Cs only</li>
<ol class="img">
  <li>CA</li>
  <li>CB</li>
</ol>
</ol> 
<div id="foo">*</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
ol.img li{background: 
  url("http://www.rabensburg.at/modules/event/images/rightarrow.gif") no-repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent;
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding-left: 16px;
}
```

*Optional jQuery (to dynamically insert an element before the `li`):*

```
$( "li" ).before( $('#foo') );
```

Comment: Is there a way I can specify this to be an actual html element instead of just a background url?

Comment: You could use jQuery `before()` to dynamically insert the element. **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmky4/16/)**

Answer (score 0):

I would use Flexbox element as I show in the code below, taken from the this site :
[Link to lists by Doron B.](https://codepen.io/Doron_B/pen/bNxQGe)

```css
ol, ul { display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: nowrap; justify-content: flex-start; margin: 1em 0px; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
li { display: flex; line-height: 1.5; position: relative; }
ol { counter-reset: numbers }
ol > li { }
ol > li:before { counter-increment: numbers; content: "" counter(numbers) ""; color: inherit; font-weight: normal; display: flex; flex: none; align-items: flex-start; justify-content: flex-end; padding-right: 0.8em; }
ol[data-subsections] { }
ol[data-subsections] li { }
ol[data-subsections] li:before { content: counters(numbers,".") " " }
ol[data-subsections] > li {font-weight: bold;}
ol[data-subsections] > li:before {font-weight: bold; }
ol[data-subsections] ol {width: 100%; flex: none; padding: 1em 0; font-weight: normal;}
```

```html
<section>
         <h5>Ordered list, subsections<code> ol data-subsections </code></h5>
         <ol data-subsections>
            <li>A</li>
            <li><a href="http://www.zzzzzzz.com">B </a>
              <ol>
                <li>Subsection</li>
                <li>Subsection
                  <ol>
                <li>Subsection</li>
                <li>Subsection</li>
                <li>Subsection</li>
              </ol>
                </li>
                <li>Subsection</li>
              </ol>
           </li>
            <li>C</li>
            <li>D</li>
            <li>E</li>
            <li>F</li>
         </ol>
      </section>
```